# Add multiple git commands to one line for use in terminal alias

Tags: git, bash

I am attempting to write a new alias command that performs the following:

```
git push origin [current branch]
```

I have the following to return the current branch

> git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

I cannot work out:

a) how to add two commands to one line and not have them run procedurally. E.g return the current branch but then also run it on one line. I have tried the following alias:

```
alias "gps cb"="git push origin \"git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD\""
```

b) how to have an alias with a space in it e.g `gps cb`, I have a separate for just `gps` so I'd rather keep the pattern of having a space afterwards in the alias so it's not too much mental legwork to write `gps master` and `gps cb`

Comment: Why do you need the alias at all? `git push` defaults to both current branch and `origin` if you don't specify, meaning that `git push` should already do what you're asking for, or am I missing something?

Comment: You may want to use a `git` alias instead of a shell alias, which would allow you to write something like `git pcb`. Untested, but I think you would add `alias.pcb = '!git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'` to your `~/.git/config` file.

Answer (score 3):

Define as:

```
push-branch() {
    git push origin "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
}
```

Use as:

```
$ push-branch
```

Note that [aliases cannot have spaces in them.](https://superuser.com/a/105389/362931) You need a function for that. You can replace your current `gps` alias with a function that takes arguments:

```
gps() {
    case "$1" in)
    cb) push-branch;;
    *) # whatever your current gps does ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an alias definition at all, which could be solved by a simple function call.

```
git-push-origin() {
    git push origin "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
}
```

and just call the function `git-push-origin` from the command line. Also you could add the function definition to `.bashrc` to load them at startup.

Answer (score 1):

git has it's own alias system, so you could do

```
git config --global alias.pushCurrent '!exec git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

which adds the git command

```
git pushCurrent
```

but just `git push` should push the head of the current branch to origin, so you probably have some special case to justify the extra alias, and you can tweak this to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitution `$()` to use the output of one command as an argument for another command.

```
git push origin "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

Spaces in aliases or function names are not possible, but even if they were allowed, I don't think you would want to use them, because you had to escape the space in order to call them (`"gps cb"` or `gps\ cb`).

If you already have defined your own `gps` script and want it to behave differently depending on the first argument, you have to use an `if` or `case` statement to check the first argument.